# How to formulate time period dummy variable in lm()

Tags: r, lm

I am analysing whether the effects of x_t on y_t differ during and after a specific time period.
I am trying to regress the following model in R using `lm()`:

```
y_t = b_0 + [b_1(1-D_t) + b_2 D_t]x_t
```

where D_t is a dummy variable with the value 1 over the time period and 0 otherwise.

Is it possible to use `lm()` for this formula?

Comment: How many periods do you have? What does the vector of periods look like?

Comment: I have 80 observations over 10 years. I want to split them up in two periods with the dummy.

Comment: When does the second period start?

Comment: At the 55th obs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
observationNumber <- 1:80
obsFactor <- cut(observationNumber, breaks = c(0,55,81), right =F)
fit <- lm(y ~ x * obsFactor)
```

For example:

```
 y = runif(80)
 x = rnorm(80) + c(rep(0,54), rep(1, 26))
 fit <- lm(y ~ x * obsFactor)
 summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x * obsFactor)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.48375 -0.29655  0.05957  0.22797  0.49617 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         0.50959    0.04253  11.983   <2e-16 ***
x                  -0.02492    0.04194  -0.594    0.554    
obsFactor[55,81)   -0.06357    0.09593  -0.663    0.510    
x:obsFactor[55,81)  0.07120    0.07371   0.966    0.337    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3116 on 76 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01303,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.02593 
F-statistic: 0.3345 on 3 and 76 DF,  p-value: 0.8004
```

`obsFactor[55,81)` is zero if `observationNumber < 55` and one if its greater or equal its coefficient is your $b_0$. `x:obsFactor[55,81)` is the product of the dummy and the variable $x_t$ - its coefficient is your $b_2$. The coefficient for $x_t$ is your $b_1$.

Comment: This is an intriguing new way of doing it! Do `obsFactor[55,81)` and `x:obsFactor[55,81)` represent coefficients for a level change and a trend change?